# Sum ITEM CODE and their alternative on one row from another table with SQL

Tags: sql, sum, sql-update, subquery

I have two table
need to sum stock for item code and their alternative on one row "Stock Column"
from other table "Stock table" with SQL .

[image]

Table 1

[image]

Stock Table

Answer (score 0):

In most databases, you can use a correlated subquery to update the items table from the stocks table:

```
update items i
set stock = (
    select sum(s.stock)
    from stocks s
    where s.itemcode = i.itemcode
)
```

That said, storing such derived information is not necessarily a good idea, because it is hard to keep it up to date. Everytime stock data is modified, you need to propagate the changes to the parent table; you will soon find yourself in need for a trigger or the-like.

An alternative is to create a view, that gives you an always up-to-date perspective at your data:

```
create view v_items as
select i.*, 
(
    select sum(s.stock)
    from stocks s
    where s.itemcode = i.itemcode
) as stock
from items i
```

Comment: after apply above VIEW it saw only on sum the first column and ignore all alternative columns